# Saving an entire one-to-many structure of transient objects in one query

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

**In Short**

I seem to have landed on a MAJOR anti-pattern of saving objects WAY too many times. I've read through the limited Objectify docs and can't seem to find the right pattern to use.

**Details**

I have multiple objects I want to store. They are all transient (they don't exist in the database yet) and they have a one-to-many relationship. I don't want to sit and call ofy().save() on every last object in my hierarchy.

In the following example, a Player has a List of Cards.

**My Model:**

```
@Entity
public class Player {
  @Id private Long id = null;//will be generated

  private List<Ref<Card>> cards = new ArrayList<Ref<Card>>();
  //getters and setters here
}

public class Card{
  @Id private Long id = null;//will be generated

  //lots of other fields and getters and setters here
}
```

**My Operation:**

I need to create a new player and new card, with the player having a reference to the card in his List "cards."

**IDEAL SOLUTION:**

I would like to just create the player and card java objects, set their relationships, and pass them to Objectify to be saved. Like this:

```
Player player = new Player();
Card card = new Card();
player.setPlayer(Ref.create(card));
ofy.save().entity(player).now();
```

That will **fail**. The 3rd line attempts to create a new Ref for Card, which cannot be done because Card doesn't have an Id yet, which will be assigned to it once it's already persisted. It seems I must never associate an object with another until one has already been saved.

**Current Crappy Solution**

So, my solution must be to save the Card first, and then relate it to the Player, then save the player.

```
Player player = new Player();
Card card = new Card();
ofy().save().entity(card).now();
player.setPlayer(Ref.create(card));
ofy().save().entity(card).now();
```

This is insane. It seems reasonable at first, but my app is dealing with many more relationships than just this, and with this pattern my algorithm will be a spiderweb of checking for transient objects inside collections before saving the entity I'm actually concerned with.

There MUST be some way to tell Objectify to just SAVE all child/related entities along with the entity I've requested, and furthermore generate the Ids necessary instead of throwing an Exception at me.

Furthermore, I'll also need this sort of "recursive save" solution even when none of my objects are transient (ie they all have IDs already). I can't waste my time iterating through collections and then all the collections WITHIN those collections and saving them all. I'm going to need some way of telling Objectify to just SAVE THIS WHOLE HEIRARCHY OF OBJECTS I just passed you.

I've been reading around this @Load annotation and I feel like maybe there's something in there I'm missing... I don't know. Need help. Documentation is slim.

**UPDATED SOLUTION**
For posterity - 
Using the allocateId() method decouples the entire ID generation constraint away from the database and you get a VERY clean pattern, particularly if you do as I did:
All database @Entity classes get a private constructor and a static public factory for creating transient objects. This static factory method ( createTransient() ) will always allocate a new ID. So then, all client code can use this method for acquiring new transient objects, or the obvious objectify load for acquiring existing persisted instances. Simple. Done. Lovely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend two things:

1. Allocate ids manually when you construct your objects using `ObjectifyFactory.allocateId()`. Do not use the "save with null autogenerates" feature. As you've noticed, it's a PITA to deal with entity objects that have null ids, so don't allow them to exist.
2. Use deferred saves. `ofy().defer().save().entity(blah);` You can save almost any number of things this way and they'll only get saved once on commit (or closing of the objectify session). Deferring save on the same entity multiple times produces only a single save.

This pattern of leaving ids null and filling it in on save is a holdover from the JPA days. It didn't work very well with JPA either; there were plenty of frustrating edge cases dealing with entities missing ids (especially when you wanted to put the in maps or sets). The best solution is to simply guarantee that no entity is ever missing an id in the first place.

Note that you'll want to allocate the id in a custom constructor, *not* the no-args constructor that Objectify uses to build your entity on load. Allocating an id is cheap but still a call to the GAE service layer and you don't want to do this on every load.

Comment: This allocateId() method is what I've been missing. Thank you sir.